# php to call MSSQL query and compare two dates?

Tags: php, sql-server, date

Ahoy there all, I am a bit stuck and need some help.

I am calling an external MSSQL (not MySQL) database from my linux server and display results AFTER today's date.  Here is the code:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");// current date
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today)));
$todaysDate = date( 'M j Y g:i:s:000A', $date ); //converts it for MSSQL standards

$query = "select DateofArrival from aTable where DateofArrival > '". $todaysDate ."'";
```

When I run the query, it displays ALL results, doesn't even give a flying hoot about the WHERE.

I am guessing that it is because it is comparing a date with a string?  Not completely sure on that one though.

Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

Update:  Here is the echoed query string.

```
$query = "select DateofArrival from aTable where DateofArrival > 'Jan 10 2012 12:00:00:000AM'";
```

date examples stored in the db:

```
Feb 28 2004 12:00:00:000AM
Oct 14 2009 12:00:00:000AM
May 18 2011 12:00:00:000AM
Apr 10 2012 12:00:00:000AM
```

Comment: Debug using `echo $query;` and run the command yourself. Likely your date format is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly in SSMS to see what you get? Also, have you checked the value of $todaysDate to make sure it is what you expect?

Comment: Doesn't MS SQL prefer `mm/dd/yyyy g:i:s`?

Comment: I have updated the original post with what it is displaying and what it is showing.  It seems the comparisons are just fine unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL/MSSQL uses standard military format, you see the "M j Y g:i:s:000A" format because you are using a software that converts the output to fit the locale of your system or the locale of the database, i'm not sure which one.

What i know for sure is that when comparing dates in MSSQL, just like in any other system, **always** use the

```
Y-m-d G:i:s
```

format. This is how databases store the data and how it expects it to be provided when you input or compare.

I've done 5 years of work in VB6 + MSSQL, so i confirm you that for sure... Nothing fancy in VB6, i had to learn the format myself.

Comment: Does `G:i:s` work too? I've always assumed and used `H:i:s` (disclaimer: I haven't used MSSQL specifically).

Comment: I think it works cause i never used to format my hours with leading 0 but then again i might be mistaken. Worst comes worst, indeed the user should use H instead of G, but don't use "h" or "g" as they are 12 hour formats.

Comment: And for MYSQL i always use G:i:s and it works for your info :)

Comment: Hmmm interesting!  So you are saying the linux server is automatically converting the data that is stored in the DB? even when I do a straight echo, I get May 18 2011 12:00:00:000AM

Comment: No, the return API is doing that, but the information in the database is not formatted like that... You can use CONVERT() to change the format of the date when selecting data. (Refer to http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx  for more info) and if you want to change it for the session, you can use SET DATEFIRST <format> to change the default format for the connection (refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907)

Comment: Gotcha, love that link. Ironically, I had seen it before, and didnt bookmark it and kicked myself for days after. :)   Well, I made the changes to the code and set up the compare again, but STILL it is showing everything.  I have honestly tried 5 or 6 variations of the date. Formatting, not formatting. CONVERT, not CONVERT.  It doesn't matter!  It HAS to be something between using mssql_query on a PHP page.  Or maybe because this is an old SQL2000 db?

Comment: My guess is your logic behind your SQL is incorrect then. I doubt that bad formatting your date is causing this. If you had a bad format, it would say that it can't convert the date or throw off an error.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well.  A date should actually be able to compare to a date, no matter what format. Like I say, I think its because I am connecting to a MSSQL database from a Linux server. There is a problem and I WILL get to the bottom of it. lol  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't format date at PHP side, because you should take into account that your web server and sql server are not in the same time zone. Instead, just make this query:

```
$query = "select DateofArrival from aTable where DateofArrival > DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))"
```

EDIT

In looks like that your dates are stored in database as string. In that case you should execute this query

```
$query = "select DateofArrival from aTable where convert(datetime, DateofArrival, 109) > DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))"
```

Comment: Hmmm... i see what you mean. I gave it a try though and it still spits out EVERYTHING.... weird, huh?

Comment: Then it means that your DateofArraival is larger than current date :) Can you give few rows from the result set? Are there really records where DateofArrivall is smaller or equal than current date?

Comment: That is in the updated original post up above.  You will see dates before and dates after. But yet, it is still displaying ALL dates. And yes, I want to display all records where the date of arrival is AFTER the current date and not display any before.  Its just not working. lol